# Is it safe to use window.location in jquery ajax response function wont it be a security thread as its exposed client side

Tags: jquery, spring, rest, spring-mvc, security

im using a jquery ajax code such as this

```
    url:'userlogin', // the function that process the  mapped url name and matching type is going to receive the data//
        type:'POST',
        data:{user_email:email,user_password:pass},// function to get the value from jsp page and send it to mapped class function//
        success: function(response){// if the backend process is success then the function will run by getting the response as its parameter//
             window.location = "http://localhost:8080/project_law/user_loginsuccess"
                        }       
    });
```

> wont it be a security thread as the javascript and jquery urls can be accessed at client side and attackers can take advantage of this success url to access this or anyother url

Comment: You using ajax request so the redirection should be done in the success handler of ajax request itself. Again you need to create webservice for authentication.

Comment: @SumeshTG thanks to your comment i was able to alter my code and make it work but i have this doubt could you please shed some light on this

Comment: Ya great question. You should pass sessionID or token in header of every ajax request(Refer `ajaxComplete,ajaxSetup`) and in server side create interceptors or filters to validate the token.

Comment: You should check authentication on the server side on every page that is not public accessible.

Comment: @SumeshTG what does that have to do with using `window.location`? You sure can't set any headers there

Comment: @charlietfl The token should store in sessionStorage or localStorage then do authentication in the front end.

Comment: @SumeshTG I didn't ask how I asked what it has to do with using window.location which is what OP is asking about. header tokens is  a complete side track to the question

Comment: window.location it is for redirection . it will change browser URL @charlietfl

Comment: @SumeshTG I am FULLY aware of that ... did you even read the question?

Comment: @charlietfl Actually he modified the question almost 100% . Initially the question is about authentication using ajax and spring mvc. I answered based on that context.